# LI fadeout on hover

Tags: jquery, opacity, html-lists

I have setup a list which when you hover over an LI the others fadeout slightly and only the one in focus is completely visible, this works fine once you have hovered over 2 but on the initial hover they all fadeout. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

```
$("#products ul ul").hover(function(){
    $('li', this).siblings().stop().animate({"opacity": .8});
},function(){
    $('li',this).stop().animate({"opacity": 1});
});

$("#products ul ul li").hover(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": 1});
},function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": .8});
});
```

Many thanks

Comment: Can you please this is to Fiddle to get right picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you mean something like this - http://jsfiddle.net/PVGS7/ ?

```
<div id="products">

<ul>
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item
        <ul>
            <li>sub list item</li>
            <li>sub list item</li>
            <li>sub list item</li>
            <li>sub list item</li>
            <li>sub list item</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item</li>
</ul>

</div>
```

and the JS

```
$("#products ul li").hover(function(){
    $(this).siblings().stop().animate({"opacity": .5});
},function(){
    $(this).siblings().stop().animate({"opacity": 1});
});
```